# How to run Laravel artisan optimize and composer when auto deploy to azure app service with github actions

Tags: php, laravel, azure, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy Laravel Application to Azure App Service (Linux).

Everything works fine but after deploy is done, I want to run artisan optimize and composer dump-autoload to optimize application.

I tried to achieve it by setting .sh file, which I run after deployment is done, but with no results.

Script throws me an error, that the app key is missing.

I don't provide .env file in GIT repository because of security reasons. I have app environments set through Configuration -> Application Settings in Azure.

If I run the script manually after I login to SSH console, everything works fine.

Thank you for your help.

Here is my autodeploy file:

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy PHP app to Azure Web App - CompanyCloudApi

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '7.4'

      - name: Check if composer.json exists
        id: check_files
        uses: andstor/file-existence-action@v1
        with:
          files: 'composer.json'

      - name: Run composer update if composer.json exists
        if: steps.check_files.outputs.files_exists == 'true'
        run: composer.phar update --lock --no-autoloader 

      - name: Run composer install if composer.json exists
        if: steps.check_files.outputs.files_exists == 'true'
        run: composer.phar install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-autoloader 

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: php-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: php-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'CompanyCloudApi'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_D8D3E40C2E1F4054A56935E2368420D4 }}
          package: .

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '7.4'

      - name: 'Run post deploy code'
        run: |
            chmod +x ./deployment_done_script.sh
            ./deployment_done_script.sh  
        shell: bash
```

And here is deployment_done_script.sh

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

If trying to run php commands inside "run" statement, like this:

```
  - name: 'Run post deploy code'
    run: |
        php artisan config:cache
        php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

I got this error:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to call your php script directly through the "run" statement ?

Comment: Yes, now. It throws another error, as is visible in my updated question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `--no-autoloader` flag from this run step.

```
run: composer.phar install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-autoloader
```

By using the `--no-autoloader` option with composer install, you're indicating that you don't want Composer to generate the autoloader file as part of the installation process.